# Symfony 5 - display an required input field after a specify dropdown select

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I would like to build a form with Symfony 5 that should display a required input field for a certain dropdown selection.

After selecting "sonstiges" I need a required input field.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('salutation', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'salutation',
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank()
                ],
                'placeholder' => 'Bitte wählen',
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'visually-hidden'
                ],
                'choices' => [
                    'Herr' => 'herr',
                    'Frau' => 'frau',
                    'Diverse' => 'diverse',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank()
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "firstname",
                ],
            ])
            ->add('afterWork', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'afterWork',
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank()
                ],
                'placeholder' => 'Bitte wählen',
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'visually-hidden'
                ],
                'choices' => [
                    'Studium' => 'studium',
                    'weitere Schule' => 'weiterSchule',
                    'Ausbildung' => 'ausbildung',
                    'Sonstiges' => 'sonstiges',
                ],
            ])
   }
```

I added a $builder->addEventListener, unfortunately it didn't give me the result I need, I also added the input field as not required, hidden it and displayed it with a javascript. Unfortunately, it will not be validated because it is not required in the $builder.

```
$builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $event->getData();

                if (!is_null($data) && $data['afterWork'] == "sonstiges") {
                    $form->add('afterWorkText', TextType::class, [
                        'label' => "afterWorkText",
                        'required' => false,
                        'constraints' => array(
                            new NotBlank(),
                        ),
                        'attr' => [
                            'placeholder' => "afterWorkText"
                        ],
                        'label_attr' => [
                            'class' => 'visually-hidden'
                        ],
                    ]);
                }
            }
```

Is there a way to insert this field with "display:none" attribute and activate it with a javascript? In addition, the field should then be set to required.

Or can someone help me to find the right solution here?

Comment: Have you read [symfony doc for dynamic form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) ? When you choose your option the form is reloaded with your choice data and automatically add you required field

Comment: sry for the late reply. I read the documentation and tried to work with the eventListener. However, I have 2 problems 1. Nothing changes dynamically on my form when I make a selection and 2. It is difficult for me to understand how I can display the field at a certain point in my FormView, since there is a change in the dropdown is not available.
I don't really get it or I'm just being stupid...